# Deploy pivotal cloud foundry on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, pcf

i got the following error when i tried to create the stack. have no idea hot to fix this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy2Ew.png)

what's the problem

Comment: Please click the link to open the details

Answer (score 0):

You should file a Pivotal Support [help ticket](https://login.support.pivotal.io/sign-in), they are pretty quick and there would be a support engineer who can guide you through the installation.

I have done this myself in the past and I am quite satisfied with the support that I received

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a ticket in [Pivotal Support](https://support.pivotal.io)